# Reading an hdf5 file only after it has completely finished acquiring data

Tags: python, hdf5

Data will be saved into hdf5 files but the saving takes roughly 30 seconds in total for one file. Once the data is done being saved in one hdf5 file, the file will be used immediately until the next hdf5 file is done and the process will continue like so. Is there a simple way to check if an hd5 file is done loading and only then can it be used? The hdf5 files are roughly 10-20MB and will all be saved in the same folder. Of course I could perhaps set a timer above 30 seconds of some sort but I am interested in keeping the time as low as possible which means I need to know exactly when each hdf5 file is finished acquiring data.

A couple of ideas I have:

1. Measuring the difference in file size from one point in time to another. If there is no change then it is assumed the file is done loading.
2. I don't know much about hdf5 files but perhaps there is something at the end of every hdf5 file and only at the end. If that is the case, I could keep checking if the values of the last component is there. If it is there then the file must be finished.

Any thoughts? I would definitely appreciate any help.

Edit:
My idea with the hdf5 part inside `on_created`:

```
class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):    

    def __init__(self, callback: Callable):
        self.callback = callback

        # Store callback to be called on every on_created event

    def on_created(self, event: Union[DirCreatedEvent, FileCreatedEvent]):
        #print(f"Event type: {event.event_type}\nAt: {event.src_path}\n")

        # check if it's File creation, not Directory creation
        if isinstance(event, FileCreatedEvent):
            file = pathlib.Path(event.src_path)

            #print(f"Processing file {file.name}\n")

            # call callback
            #self.callback(file)

            wait = 3
            max_wait = 30
            waited = 0

            while True:
                try:
                    h5py.File(self.callback(file), 'r')
                    return self.callback(file)

                except FileNotFoundError:
                    print('Error: HDF5 File not found')
                    return None

                except OSError:
                    if waited < max_wait:
                        print(f'Error: HDF5 File locked, sleeping {wait} seconds...')
                        time.sleep(wait)
                        waited += wait
                    else:
                        print(f'waited too long= {waited} secs')
                        return None
```

Comment: How are the hd5 files being written? By an external program, a program you have control over, or the same program?

Comment: Also, is each file being written by different programs/processes? or the same program?

Comment: It's an internal program that writes the hdf5 files but there should be no communication between this program and the program I want to use. Only the hdf5 files should be used after the internal program is done writing the files. Every file is written by the same program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments and our discussion, the easiest implementation might be a function that "waits" for the file, but does not return the h5py file object. This way you still use the standard context manager: (e.g., `with h5py.File() as h5f:`)  and avoid the need to close the file in the main program.

I am posting the modified function as a new answer (renamed to `h5_wait`) to avoid confusion (my first answer has the original function `h5_open_wait`). This function is similar, but returns a `True/False` flag instead of a h5py file object. It checks the file status by calling `h5py.File()`, then closes before exiting the function.  Also it uses a `sys.argv` to get the HDF5 filename (as `sys.argv[1]`).

**See new code below:**

```
import h5py
import sys
import time

def h5_wait(h5file):
    
    wait = 3
    max_wait = 30
    waited = 0

    while True:
        try:
            h5f = h5py.File(h5file,'r')
            break
                
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('\nError: HDF5 File not found\n')
            return False
        
        except OSError:   
            if waited < max_wait:
                print(f'Warning: HDF5 File locked, sleeping {wait} seconds...')
                time.sleep(wait) 
                waited += wait  
            else:
                print(f'\nWaited too long= {waited} secs, exiting...\n')
                return False

    h5f.close()
    return True

####################

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.exit('Include HDF5 file name on command line.')
h5file = sys.argv[1]         

h5stat = h5_wait(h5file)
if h5stat is False:
    sys.exit('Error: HDF5 File not available')
    
with h5py.File(h5file) as h5f:
    # do something with the file      
    start = time.time()
    for ds, obj in h5f.items():
        print(f'ds name={ds}; shape={obj.shape}')
      
    print(f'\nTime to read {len(list(h5f.keys()))} datasets = {time.time()-start:.2f} secs')
```

Comment: How does `sys.argv` retrieve a new file? Files will be coming in every 30 seconds so I am not seeing how sys.argv does check for new populated h5 files.

Comment: It doesn't. :-) They value is passed when the program starts. How does your 'watchdog program' pass the names of new files to the next program when it finds them?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is 'file locking'. The good news: This is enabled (by default) with HDF5 libraries builds. AND, better yet, it is enabled in the h5py package! So, you will get an exception if you try to open a file that is open for writing by another program. We can use that exception to our advantage. The challenge is differentiating the file locked exception from other potential file open exceptions (like file does't exist).

Frankly, I prefer Python's `with/as:` context manager to open files. However, it handles all exceptions the same (doesn't open, and exits). So, we need a way to handle different exceptions differently. I suspect a custom file context manager is the most Pythonic way to do this. However, that goes beyond my expertise.

Instead, I wrote a function you call with the filenameIt uses `try/except:` in a `while` loop to open the file. One of 3 things will happen:

1. It returns the h5py file object if it opens the file.
2. It immediately returns `None`if the file doesn't exist.
3. If it is locked, it sleeps, then retries again. If it can't open after the time limit, None is returned.

Remember to use the `.close()` method when using this function!

**Code updated 2021-09-09 to pass HDF5 file name as required command line argument using `argparse` module.**
**updated Code below:**

```
import h5py
import argparse
import sys 
import time

def h5_open_wait(h5file):
    
    wait = 3
    max_wait = 30
    waited = 0

    while True:
        try:
            h5f = h5py.File(h5file,'r')
            return h5f
                
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('Error: HDF5 File not found')
            return None
        
        except OSError:   
            if waited < max_wait:
                print(f'Error: HDF5 File locked, sleeping {wait} seconds...')
                time.sleep(wait) 
                waited += wait  
            else:
                print(f'waited too long= {waited} secs')
                return None

def get_job_options():

# Note that HDF5 file name is only parameter and is required; 
 
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Check HDF5 file is available to open.')
    parser.add_argument('hdf5', help='HDF5 filename (Required)' )

    if len(sys.argv)==1:
    # display help message when no args are passed.
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit('Error: No HDF5 file name specified; exiting.')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    HDF5_FILE = args.hdf5
    #print ('HDF5 file = %s' % args.hdf5)

    return (HDF5_FILE)

####################

h5file  = get_job_options()

start = time.time()

h5f = h5_open_wait(h5file)
if h5f is None:
    sys.exit('Error: HDF5 File not opened')
    
# do something with the file      
for ds, obj in h5f.items():
    print(f'ds name={ds}; shape={obj.shape}')

h5f.close()     
print(f'\nTime to read all datasets = {time.time()-start:.2f} secs')
```

To test, I wrote a simple program that creates 800 data sets from a large array. (Code below.) To test, start this first, then run the code above to see how it waits. Adjust `max_wait` above and `a0` and `cnt` below as appropriate for your system speed.

**Code to create the example file used above:**

```
start = time.time()
a0 = 1000
cnt = 800
arr = np.random.random(a0*a0).reshape(a0,a0)
with h5py.File('SO_69067142.h5','w') as h5f:
    for dcnt in range(cnt):
        h5f.create_dataset(f'ds_{dcnt:03}',data=arr)

print(f'Time to create {cnt} datasets={time.time()-start:.2f}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also need that the function somehow checks/selects the next newest file in the folder so that it is a smooth continuous process of checking if A.hdf5 is finished writing. When yea the file is returned and used elsewhere. Then the program checks for a newer file in the folder. If it finds a newer file, B.hdf5, then the process continues to see if it is finished B.hdf5 finished writing. But it should only check if a newer file is added and not check older files. Do you know a way to do this? This was part of my question which I also haven't been able to solve.

Comment: That process is a completely different question (and more complicated). :-) If I understand, you might have: `A.hdf5`, `B.hdf5`, `C.hdf5`, `D.hdf5`, etc. It's relatively straight-forward if they all exist when the program starts. Create a dictionary of file names and iterate over them until all have been processed. However, if they don't exist when the program starts, you will need another loop to check for new files and add them to the dictionary for processing. It's not hard, but tricky. Also, how will you know when you are done (when to stop checking for new files)?

Comment: Yea exactly new files will be populated with time and will be populated one by one. That means if F.hdf5 is currently being checked if it is finished, only G.hdf5 will be populated within a time window after F.hdf5 and not additionally H.hdf5 I.hdf5 J.hdf5 etc. The problem with having a dictionary of all these files being accumulated is that there will be perhaps 10000+ hdf5 files in there. I don't think that will be good with optimization since it will have to verify if the new file is already in the dictionary.

Comment: It should run theoretically forever. This is just a small part of a program. Once the main program starts, it should start searching. When the main program ends, this searching program will also end.

Comment: You may want to rethink your approach. Instead of a file based procedure, use one based on process/task status.  Start the first process (to create the HDF5 file), then after the first process has completed, start the second process.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change how the hdf5 files are created. I just need to verify that the current hdf5 file is done writing and use it for the main program. Then check for a new/next hdf5 file and do the same. You think that would be very complicated to implement?

Comment: Your comment "_It should run theoretically forever_" is what concerns me. If I understand, the main program creates the HDF5. Does the main program create all of the files from 1 run?  Or does it run multiple times (and each time creates a new file)? Either way, it seems like the main program can spawn a new process to run your program once a new HDF file is closed. If not, you need a program that constantly monitors the system for new files...(forever?)

Comment: I wouldn't cause that too much alarm. I just mean that it will keep searching as long as the main program is running. When the main program is off, the search program is off. The main program isn't the black box that creates the hdf5 files. The black box creates the files consecutively: one is made, when that one is finished it moves on to creating the next one. So the black box is what is making the hdf5 files. The main program tells the blackbox to run, the blackbox runs and creates the hdf5 files. Once the main program is off, the blackbox is off and so will be the search program.

Comment: Does that make sense? Would it be possible if we chat on discord or slack or something? You seem like you know a lot about hdf5 files and I am really wanting to learn as much as possible. Would it be possible to discuss this further somewhere more convenient?

Comment: Ok, that helps a little. Sure, we can discuss. I don't use slack or discord. Is the SO chat room OK?

Comment: Yea that could work but do you use something else? Would be nice to keep in touch with you if I could ask you things in the future if you would be up for it.

Comment: OK, click on Add Comment, then auto-magically move this to chat, and we can continue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236867/discussion-between-kcw78-and-mikanim).

Comment: Are you available today?

Comment: You there? I would like to discuss this issue further in the chat if you have time.

Comment: Yes, I am available today.

Comment: Ok I am available now if you are as well

Comment: chat started I think you can use the link above

Comment: btw is it necessary to wait for 3? I think I can do without the max wait time as well as from the watchdog part I will exit the class that runs this code.

Comment: `wait` is how long the program waits (sleeps) before the next check. `max_wait` is the maximum time the program will wait before exiting with an exception. I set `max_wait=30` b/c your OP said "_set a timer above 30 seconds_'. I think you want a max value to avoid an indefinite loop (say the blackbox creates a file and doesn't close cleanly). Modify both values to suit your needs.

Comment: Ok great. DId you make the changes from yesterday?

Comment: Yes, I added `def get_job_options()` to read and return the HDF5 filename. It is called in the body of the main code (see `h5file  = get_job_options()` ).

Comment: I don't think the parser part is needed no?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. I usually have several command line options, some required, some optional. So I use argparse package. If you only want to pass the H5 file name, you could check sys.args.

Comment: Essentially I already have the file from watchdog. So all I need to do next is just verify that the h5 file is done writing. That means I just need the the function `h5_open_wait()` function. Right?

Comment: Yep, assuming your main program is written in Python, all you need is `def h5_open_wait()`, then call the function with your filename. Remember - this isn't a context manager, so don't forget to `close()` the file.

Comment: If I just use the content of the `h5_open_wait()` and put it into a different function that is in a class, do I still need to call `close()`? I made an edit of what I mean.

Comment: Yes, if you open the file, you need to close it "somewhere". The function calls `h5py.File()` to open and return a h5py file object (or None). If you don't close, you leave the file in an undetermined state. You could modify the class to be a context manager by adding `def __enter__` and and `def __exit`. Then use `with / as` to open the file and it is automatically closed when you exit that code block.

Comment: I thought of a more Pythonic approach. Instead of opening the file with the "h5_open_wait" function, I think it's better to test if the file is available and return a True/False flag. This way, the rest of your code will use standard Python calls. I posted the new function as a new answer below.